# Getting the size of a /proc/kallsyms symbol

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel, perf, debug-symbols

The pseudo-file `/proc/kallsyms` gives you a list of kernel symbols and their addresses, like so:

```
ffffffffaf2b64b0 t try_to_unmap_one
ffffffffaf2b7d40 T try_to_unmap
ffffffffaf2b8fd0 t vunmap_pmd_range.isra.0
ffffffffaf2ba360 t _vm_unmap_aliases.part.0
ffffffffaf2ba4b0 T vm_unmap_aliases
ffffffffaf2bcb50 T vunmap_range_noflush
```

For functions, this is the *start* address, but how I can I get the end address, i.e., the *size* of the function? The subsequent address provides an upper bound on this value, but it is not precise and there is no subsequent address for the final symbol.

Comment: Do you also have a kernel image file with ELF metadata from the `.size` directives compilers use?  It appears Linux doesn't export that via `/proc/kallsyms`

Comment: @PeterCordes - well I could get that, but then I wouldn't really need `/proc/kallsyms` at all. `kallsyms` is nice because (a) it is basically always there and (b) it (AFAIK) encodes the actual symbol addresses after KASLR, while the image won't do that. Probably the answer to this question is "you can't, just use the start of the next symbol as a proxy", but just thought I'd check.